# find the exact numbers that have 3 divisors and are smaller than n(given by the user)

Tags: python

I am a 9th grader that just learned some basic algorithms in pseudocode and tried solving a problem in python. The ex. required me to find the numbers that have 3 divisors and are smaller than n. what should I do? there is no output

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a69tA.png**strong text**

```
n=int(input("introduce a  nr"))
x=1
k=0
d=1
for x in range(1,n+1):
    for d in range(1,x+1):
        if x % d==0:
            k+=1
        d+=1
    if k==3:
      print(x)
    x+=1
```

Comment: Please include your code as text not images.

Comment: What is the point of `d+=1`? The for-loop automatically increments `d`. Also -- notice that you are *not* re-initializing `k` for each pass through the inner loop. If you simply move `k=0` down a few lines (and properly indented) you get very different output.

Comment: you are right,im sorry,same for x+=1

Comment: it works,thank you mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not reinitializing `k` beofre for each invocation of the inner loop. Another problem is that you are not trusting `for` loops to do what they are designed to do. Things like `d += 1` are pointless.

The following code works:

```
n=int(input("introduce a  nr: "))

for x in range(1,n+1):
    k = 0
    for d in range(1,x+1):
        if x % d==0:
            k+=1
    if k==3:
      print(x)
```

The output (for `n = 1000`) is:

```
4, 9, 25, 49, 121, 169, 289, 361, 529, 841, 961
```

Interestingly, this is sequence [A001248](https://oeis.org/A001248) in the On-line encyclopedia of integer sequences. That sequence is describes as being the sequence of all squares of primes. It is easy to see that this another way of describing the sequence that you are trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

Some extra when you want to know by which numbers it can be divided:``

```
#!/bin/env python3

n = int(input("introduce a  nr: "))
for x in range(1, n+1):
    diverders = []
    for d in range(1, x+1):
        if x % d == 0:
            diverders.append(d)

    if len(diverders) == 3:
        print(f'{x} can be devided by {diverders}')
```